# Access a variable from a jsp file

Tags: javascript, jsp, listview

I have created two jsp pages. I passed a list from jsp page and displayed the contents of the list in the second page using this: ${user.rate},${user.location}etc..

Now, I want to store one of these elements in a local variable for performing some arithmetic operations. I don't know how to save the variables locally and use it.

Kindly help me.

Comment: I'd say you're in the wrong place. StackOverflow is for programming questions only, and this seems like it belongs either to https://superuser.com or https://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I used c tags to store my values.

`<c: set var=name_of_variable value=${user.location} />`
And I can access the variable using the 'name_of_variable'.